# How do I extract a string from user input?

Tags: c

```
milage = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
drive(&cars[carID-1], milage);
```

I have something like this for numbers, I want to use same thing for a name (character).

I tried this:

```
user = strtok(NULL, " ");
rent(&cars[carID-1], user);
```

but it did not work out.

Can any one help?

Comment: Define `work` first. Give minimal example of the code that can be compiled and ran, and describe what you want it to do. Otherwise this is not a question.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just trying to extract numbers / strings from within another string?
If that is the case you should probably have a look at [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/). It works just like `scanf` but reads froms a string instead of from the standard input.

```
char name[100]; int mileage;
sscanf("username 42", "%s %d", name, &mileage);
//name now contains "username" and mileage now contains 42
```

Comment: how should I use sscanf if there is incoming value from user?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can't you just use the regular scanf in this case?

Answer (score 0):

char * is not a string type. char * is a pointer to byte array. Byte array is the string type.

Strings can be copied with strdup(). Copied strings need to be freed with free().